# Natural versus Unatural splitting, the difference is....

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I am working on an assignment currently and come across the Universa Coefficient Theorem for Homology/Cohomology. I am still getting somewhat used to the terminology and concepts in questions but I have understood that splitting a SES
$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$
implies that $B\cong A \oplus C$, amongst other things which the splitting lemma says. This is the first time I come across a splitting that isn't "natural" to which I am stumped, what does it mean for a splitting to not be natural? Or for that matter for it to be "natural" is also a good question so I understand the distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms that appear in the universal coefficient theorem are not just abelian groups; they are [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) taking values in abelian groups, and the morphisms in the universal coefficient theorem are [natural transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation). To ask for a natural splitting is to ask for a splitting which also organizes into a natural transformation.

Comment: Why does things keep coming back to haunt me!? So does it have to do with that in a "natural splitting" you can get a natural transformation, but in unnatural you cannot?

Comment: @Zelos: yes, that's what I just said.

Comment: I am making certain so I understand it correctly, thank you for the input.